# Generating road mesh from a graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, mesh, unreal-engine4, procedural-generation, topology

**Background:**
I got a **unidirectional planner graph**, each node in the graph contains its location and to which nodes it's connected to(up to 4 nodes each one in a separated variable).
Each connection between nodes is an edge, a road segment and each node is a junction\dead end.
The road should follow a 2D **polar** grid layout and will be edited in runtime.
This will be used as a road-building tool for city building game.
I'm using UE4 C++ and I'm pretty new to procedural generation.

**The issue:**
I'm looking for some guidance on how to generate the topology.
1. What algorithms\method\technic\math I should use or know about?
2. If I should use the extrude method then how do I include the junctions?
3. Where should I have overlapping verts? (other then places where I need to cut for UVs)
4. How do I incorporate sidewalk to the road segments and the junctions

**Research:**
The best way that I found is basically the extrude method which seems too primitive and will be problematic with intersections since it requires to lookup verts locations which seems extremely inefficient.

**More details about the graph:**
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/179214/generate-road-mesh-from-a-graph
(I'm posting here because game dev seems to be pretty dead sadly)

Comment: If the graph is 2d (no tunnels or such), I would keep a 2d matrix in parallel (or quadtree) where the position of the roads is informed this would help to quickly determine overlaps (instead of traversing the graph). Other than that maybe post this on a math forum.